# Reading IA32 Assembly Code pertaining to using double arrays

Tags: assembly, x86

This is the exact question:

> The following Code transposes the elements of an M x M array, where M
>   is a constant defined by #define:

```
void transpose(Marray_t A) {
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < M; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
           int t = A[i][j];
           A[i][j] = A[j][i];
           A[j][i] = t;
       } 
}
```

> When compiled with optimization level -02, GCC generates the following
>   code for the inner loop of the function:

```
1. .L3 
2. movl (%ebx),%eax 
3. movl (%esi,%ecx,4),%edx 
4. movl %eax, (%esi,%ecx,4) 
5. addl $1, %ecx 
6. movl %edx, (%ebx) 
7. addl $52,%ebx 
8. cmpl %edi,%ecx 
9. jl .L3
```

> A. What is the value of M?
>
> B. What registers hold program values i and
>   j?
>
> C. Write a C code version of transpose that makes use of the
>   optimizations that occur in this loop. Use the parameter M in your
>   code rather than numeric constant.

So in my attempts to understand this, I notice that it is multiplying by 4, which means it stores types of 4 bytes (maybe an int or a pointer). Then, it increments i by $52 (I assume i) since it's a larger value, thus going to the next array) and $52 / 4 is 13. So I would guess that M = 13. Wrong?

For B, I would guess that %ebx contains i and %ecx contains i.

For C, I'm not exactly sure because I don't completely understand the loop presented. Let me try to understand by line number and tell me where I'm wrong. 1. is the beginning of the loop label obviously. 2. moves presumably the value of i into %eax. Then 3. has A[i][j] being stored into t. But... I really don't understand it. :/ Help??

Answer (score 7):

I fixed some mistakes in the assembly code (`%ecs` -> `%ecx` and `(ebx) -> (%ebx)`) I hope I didn't inadvertently introduce new errors.

On to the questions, where you are almost there with the understanding. Let's take the code line by line and attempt to translate it to C.

```
   L3:
2. movl (%ebx),%eax
   // We load a 32-bit value from the address stored in ebx. We can't yet deduce the type, but let's assume int for now
   int *ebx = ??;         
   int eax = *ebx; 
3. movl (%esi,%ecx,4),%edx
   // As you noted we're dealing with 32-bit values, so when converting to C we divide the index by 4
   int *esi = ??;
   int ecx = ??; 
   int edx = esi[ecx]; 
4. movl %eax, (%esi,%ecx,4)
   esi[ecx] = eax; 
5. addl $1, %ecx 
   ecx++;
6. movl %edx, (%ebx)
   *ebx = edx; 
7. addl $52,%ebx
   // Again we have to remember to divide by the size of the type used (4)
   ebx += 13; 
8. cmpl %edi,%ecx 
9. jl .L3
   int edi = ??; 
   if (ecx < edi) goto L3;
```

From this we see that we have some unknown values that are initialized outside the inner loop, but we can also give good guesses as to what they are.

- `ecx` is incremented each loop iteration and then used to decide if we should continue the loop: it's obviously `j` from the C code.
- `edi` is the value we compare `j` to when deciding whether to loop, but it isn't changed in the inner loop: it's `i`.
- `esi` is indexed with row-wise with `ecx` (`j`), so it corresponds to `&a[i][j]`.
- `ebx` is incremented by 52 (13 index positions) each loop iteration - as you might have guessed 13 is M - it corresponds to `&m[j][i]` and is moved to point at the `j`-th row element of the next column each iteration.

Now we can answer the questions:

> A. What is the value of M?

13

> B. What registers hold program values i and j?

`edi` and `ecx` respectively.

> C. Write a C code version of transpose that makes use of the optimizations that occur in this loop. Use the parameter M in your code rather than numeric constant.

This should be straight-forward at this point.